# Proper connection to external disk via USB3

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3

With a small internal disk in my laptop (Macbook Pro Retina), I need an external disk. Sitting on the couch, the cable disconnects easily. What hardware setup can I use to prevent this from happening?

Comment: To prevent this from happening, I'd recommend you to consider upgrading your internal storage, rather than keeping an external constantly connected to your laptop, @SPRBRN! Portable hard drives are not designed to be constantly connected to a computer and they regularly spin down, when not being accessed. I'd suggest you use your external drive as a backup device and **COPY** all your important data to it. Having multiple backups is the surest way to avoid potential data loss. 
An external drive that randomly disconnects from the laptop when moved around hides great danger for your files.

Comment: Well, an upgrade to 1TB would cost me €1200, and I don't know if that's even possible. I would have a better laptop then, but it's simply not an option I would consider, unless I win the lottery.